# Combine the arrays in these datasets of a HDF5 file and finally get a 2D

Tags: python, performance, numpy, numpy-ndarray, hdf5

I have an `HDF5` file and it contains 500 datasets (named A000, A001, A002, A003 .... A499) and each dataset contains arrays of (200, 5400) sizes. I want to combine the arrays in these datasets and finally get a 2D array. For this, I can achieve the result by doing certain manipulations in the `for` loop, but this process takes a long time. So what I did is like this:

```
for datasets in my_list:
    dataset = f[(datasets)][:]
    
    i_data = dataset['real']
    q_data = dataset['imag']
    
    # power = 10.log(10.(I^2+Q^2)+1)
    power = np.log10(((np.add(np.square(np.abs(i_data)),np.square(np.abs(q_data ))))*10)+1)*10

    power = np.rot90(power)
    
    power_list.append(power)

    print("Dataset: ", datasets)

power = np.concatenate(power_list,1)
```

So, is there any way to doing this in shorter time like maybe without `for` loop.

Comment: Have you thought about reading and concatenating `i_data` and `q_data` inside the for loop, the doing your power calculation once? Also, I think concatenating reallocates the array (which really copies the existing and new data to a new array). You can avoid this by allocating `i_data` and `q_data` in advance, then use numpy slice notation to write each dataset to the proper indices.

Comment: Obviously (from `h5py` docs) you have to load each dataset individually; so that loop is necessary.  It might be possible to concatenate first and then do the `power` calculations (maybe using `stack` to make a (500, 200, 5400) 3d array.  But even if it is possible it might not save time.  It's a case of a few (only 500) iterations on a complex task.  It's hard to say, without testing, just which steps are taking the most time.